# Query staying too long on "creating sort index"

Tags: mysql

I've a query against our BI database that is taking too long to run (almost 10 minutes)

The query spends almost all that time in the state "creating sort index". 
MySQL docs are no help since it states that this status shows up when a internal table is missing.

How can I fix it?

Thanks

--EDIT:

Here are the relevant SQLs:

SELECT * FROM POWERBI_FUNIL

POWERBI_FUNIL definition:

```
SELECT 
    `FC`.`id_date` AS `id_date`,
    `FC`.`id_tenant` AS `id_tenant`,
    `FC`.`id_portfolio` AS `id_portfolio`,
    SUM(`FC`.`documents_qtt`) AS `documents_qtt`,
    SUM(`FC`.`has_any_contact_qtt`) AS `has_any_contact_qtt`,
    SUM(`FC`.`has_email_qtt`) AS `has_email_qtt`,
    SUM(`FC`.`has_phone_qtt`) AS `has_phone_qtt`
FROM
    (`BI_summarized`.`POWERBI_FUNIL_MAXDATE` `MX`
    JOIN `BI_summarized`.`fact_contacts` `FC` ON (((`FC`.`id_date` = `MX`.`id_date`)
        AND (`FC`.`id_tenant` = `MX`.`id_tenant`)
        AND (`FC`.`id_portfolio` = `MX`.`id_portfolio`))))
WHERE
    (`FC`.`id_date` >= 2426)
GROUP BY `FC`.`id_date` , `FC`.`id_tenant` , `FC`.`id_portfolio`
```

And for POWERBI_FUNIL_MAXDATE:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(`BI_summarized`.`fact_contacts`.`id_date`) AS `id_date`,
    `BI_summarized`.`fact_contacts`.`id_tenant` AS `id_tenant`,
    `BI_summarized`.`fact_contacts`.`id_portfolio` AS `id_portfolio`
FROM
    `BI_summarized`.`fact_contacts`
WHERE
    (`BI_summarized`.`fact_contacts`.`id_date` >= 2426)
GROUP BY `BI_summarized`.`fact_contacts`.`id_tenant` , `BI_summarized`.`fact_contacts`.`id_portfolio`
```

Comment: You really need to provide the sql. Also, think about how mysql is going to optimise your query, whether the relevant indexes - where? order by? - exist or not (consider creating missing ones), and whether you are processing data unnecessarily (e.g. deriving columns on a large data set before then filtering it down to a small one). Some DBMS's are better at all this than others and will effectively rewrite your query for you, I don't personally know how good mysql is, but others will.

Comment: I am probably missing something, but I don't understand why the main SELECT is grouped - surely the FROM clause produces a single row per date/tenant/portfolio anyway, and the SUMs are only ever summing one value?

Comment: MandyShaw Nope. There are several values per date/tenant/portfolio

Comment: OK. Do you need the WHERE clause in the main SELECT given that it is also present in the MAXDATE view SELECT?

Comment: I don't. However its there to limit the sets and improve performance.

Comment: But you are starting the join with the MAXDATE view, which by definition excludes all the unwanted rows anyhow. The redundant WHERE clause is very unlikely to /improve/ performance but it may well make it worse. I would try removing it.